# how to remove invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10**5'

Tags: python-3.6

How to input 10**5 in Python?

```
i = int(input()) // it gives error when I input 10**5
```

Error message is

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: 10**5.

Comment: you need to use an expression parser, as `10**5` **is not a literal number but an expression**. Alternatively if your expressions are simple you can try parsing them yourself

Comment: How do I input 10**5, If I want to?

Comment: Here is an expression parser engine [Xpresion](https://github.com/foo123/Xpresion) that works for python as well (ps I am the author). There are others as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use **eval()** function which execute your expression 
For example:

```
i = int(eval(input()))
print (i)
```

Input:

```
10**2
```

Output:

```
100
```

Comment: `eval` is a simple way to overcome the issue (and not use an expression parser or try to parse yourself), but note that **eval can be evil**

Comment: exactly sir, but I just give one alternative option for this specific scenario.